# how to count header files in linux command?

Tags: c, linux, header

I would like to know I can count how many specific header files some files include

How many distinct specific calls some files contain (for example "#include" calls)

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1):

- If you want to count only header files in folder and subfolder using
  this,

  ```
  **find . -iname "*.h" -type f | wc -l**
  ```
- If you want to count only source files in folder and subfolder using
  this,

  ```
  **find . -iname "*.c" -type f | wc -l**
  ```
- If you want to count only library files in folder and subfolder using
  this,

  ```
  **find . -iname "*.a" -type f | wc -l**
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` with the `-c` flag to count

For a list of files to search in like file1 and file2:

`grep -c #include file1 file2 ...`

Or recursively in a directory:

`grep -c -r  "#include" ~/MyCPrograms/`